# json decode for special characters

Tags: php, json

I have a string `test  éàå`. when I am performing a json_encode, the special character is being converted to `test  u00e9u00e0u00e5`.

Now when performing a json_decode, I am not getting back the original characters but instead it is remaining as `test  u00e9u00e0u00e5`

Can someone help me to have the special character back.

Comment: **HINT**: `u00e9` is UTF8 encode for `é`

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` and `json_decode` only work with UTF-8 encoded strings.

To ensure it displays correctly in your webpage, use utf-8 charset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">    
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $string = 'test éàå';
    $json = json_encode($string);
    echo json_decode($json);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks...this works perfect. But what if I am inserting an array of data in a database and trying to get it back, e.g

json_encode($_POST);

And I try to do this json_decode($result)

It stills give me the encoded special character.

Comment: Ensure the html form is in utf-8, and you should have no problem inserting and retriving the data.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid ques.
How can I ensure this. And also I am using a index.php and then performing an insert into dbase